# Create file from assets folder

Tags: flutter

I try to create File object from `assets` folder. The folder is on the same level as `android` or `lib` folders.

pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/data.csv
```

the code

```
final File csvFile = File('assets/data.csv');
final Stream<List> inputStream = csvFile.openRead();
```

and then I use the `inputStream`, but I get the error

> FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/data.csv' (OS
>   Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Answer (score 0):

please check assets directory you have created there must be some spelling error

after that click on File/invalidate the cache and restart

it should work

Comment: there is no spelling error, I renamed assets dir to res dir and made `File/invalidate the cache and restart` - the same error

Answer (score -1):

Check if the file is actually there is in assets directory
Since you have added the path of the file in pubspec.yaml, then you can directly mention the file name.

```
final File csvFile = File('data.csv');
```

Give it a try

Comment: Have you actually drag&dropped the file in the assets folder. I mean, is the file actually there?